# mvc5 Multiple models in a view use Tuple

Tags: tuples, asp.net-mvc-5

page partial view:

```
Models.SeededCategories
@if (Model.Categories.Any(s => s.ParentId == Model.Seed))
{
    <ul>
        @foreach (var node in Model.Categories)
        {
            if (node.ParentId == Model.Seed)
            {
                var inner = new Models.SeededCategories {Seed = node.Id, Categories = Model.Categories};
                <li>
                    @{if (inner.Categories.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ParentId == node.Id) != null)
                      {
                          <input type="checkbox" id="@node.Id"/><label><input type="checkbox" checked=@node.Check name="@node.ParentId" value="@node.Name"/><span></span></label><label for="@node.Id">@node.Name</label>
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          <input type="checkbox" id="@node.Id"/><label><input type="checkbox" checked=@node.Check name="@node.ParentId" value="@node.Name"/><span></span></label><span>@node.Name</span>
                      }
                    }
                    @Html.Partial("_TreeCategories", inner)
                </li>
            }
        }
    </ul>
}
```

and in view:

```
 @model Tuple<Models.SeededCategories,Models.InsertNews>
 @Html.Partial("_TreeCategories", Model.Item1,new ViewDataDictionary())
```

Error below:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'SeededCategories', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Tuple`2[SeededCategories,InsertNews]

i have two models in view page because use Of both please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solve problem with:

insert code into ActionResult in Controller:

```
var tuple = new Tuple<SeededCategories, InsertNews>(new SeededCategories { Seed = null, Categories = categories }, new InsertNews());
return View(tuple);
```